# Get input values of dynamically created input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm relatively new to web development, what i'm trying to achieve is an array of all the input values of the current row for each row found, for example: test1, true

While i'm able to get the dynamically created input values, i end up with a bunch of blanks, possibly headers? I'm also not sure my method of obtaining the values is the best solution either. Here is what i have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/gcL9H/2/

```
<table id='categoriesTable' border='1'>
<tr>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>X</th>
</tr>
<tr id='data'>
    <td><input value='test1' type='text' /></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<button id="addRow">Add</button>
<button id="saveCategories">Results</button>
```

```
$('#addRow').click(function()
{
    $('#categoriesTable').append("<tr></tr><tr></tr><td><input type='text'/></td><td><input type='checkbox'/></td>");
});

$('#saveCategories').click(function()
{
    $("#categoriesTable tr").each(function()
    {
        var row = [];
        $(this).find('td').each(function()
        {
            var type = $(this).find('input').attr('type');
            if(type == "text")
                row.push($(this).find('input').val());
            else
            if(type == "checkbox")
                row.push($(this).find('input').is(":checked"));
        })
        alert(row);
    })
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the extra `<tr>` tags in your `addRow` click handler?

Comment: You've tagged this "php" but uses none, do you want a solution in PHP or jQuery? As this can be accomplished in both.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gcL9H/7/

Comment: Thanks Christopher if you post it as an answer i'll mark accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in other answers, you add a markup issue with the `<tr>` tag

```
$('#addRow').click(function(){
    $('#categoriesTable').append("<tr><td><input type='text'/></td><td><input type='checkbox'/></td></tr>");
});
```

Collect the text / checkbox values in an array of objects :

```
$('#saveCategories').click(function(){
     var rows = [];
    // iterates each TR, skip header one
    $("#categoriesTable tr").each(function()   {
        if ( $('td',this).length>0) { // exclude header row
            var $td = $('td',this);
            // push an object of the row with label / checked properties
            rows.push({                
                label: $td.eq(0).find('input').val(),
                checked:  $td.eq(1).find('input').is(':checked')
            });
        }
    });

    // display results
    $("#results").empty();
    $(rows).each(function(index,element) {
        $("#results").append('row:' + index + ', label:' + element.label + ', checked:' + element.checked + '<br/>'); 
    });
});
```

I added a `<div id="results"></div>` to diplay collected values.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gcL9H/13/

Comment: Accepted this for the extra help in handling results, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#addRow').click(function() {
  $('#categoriesTable').append("<tr><td><input type='text'/></td><td><input type='checkbox'/></td></tr>");
});
```

Simply kill the extra `<tr>` tags and wrap the entire template string with `<tr>` and you should be good to go. You were pulling in extra tags each time you added.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcL9H/8/)

Answer (score 0):

There were two issues:

Extra row's are being added:

```
$('#categoriesTable').append("<tr><td><input type='text'/></td><td><input type='checkbox'/></td></tr>");
// Remove all the extra <tr></tr>'s and just have one <tr> at the start, 
// one </tr> at the end
```

Add a class to your first row so you could ignore this one

```
<tr class="header">
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>X</th>
</tr>
```

and have your selection as follows:

```
$("#categoriesTable tr:not(.header)").each(function()
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gcL9H/3/